# Connection SQL Server with PHP does not work

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc

I want to establish SQL Server connection with PHP.
I use the following code

```
<?php
$serverName = "serverName\\sqlexpress"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbName", "UID"=>"userName", "PWD"=>"password");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

and they return this to me

> Connection could not be established.
> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IM006 [SQLSTATE] => IM006 [1] => 0 [code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][Gestionnaire de pilotes ODBC] �chec SQLSetConnectAttr du pilote [message] => [Microsoft][Gestionnaire de pilotes ODBC] �chec SQLSetConnectAttr du pilote ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 01000 [SQLSTATE] => 01000 [1] => 5701 [code] => 5701 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Changed database context to 'DB_NAME'. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Changed database context to 'DB_NAME'. ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 01000 [SQLSTATE] => 01000 [1] => 5703 [code] => 5703 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Changed language setting to us_english. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Changed language setting to us_english. ) )

All the drivers are well installed. The SQL Server extensions are good in `php.ini`.

With `odbc_connect` the connection works but subsequently I cannot use it because my project is on codeIgniter 4 and odbc is not supported.

When I enter the wrong password an error message is displayed so I don't understand why it puts me in could not be established.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: All the which drivers are installed? What version of pdo_sqlsrv? What version of sqlsrv? Also ODBC Driver 11 is reasonably old, intended for SQL Server 2014 and earlier on Windows Server 2012 and earlier.

Comment: I am working with SQL Server 2014 and here is my pdo_sqlsrv version : 5.9.0+14116

Comment: @Zhorov 
sqlsrv is enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good problem solved.
I am going from ODBC driver 11 to ODBC driver 17, I think version 11 is not compatible with new versions of php.

Answer (score 0):

Question, this code example you provided is out of the PHP manual word for word.  Did you actually change the parameters in the connection string for your specific database?

Also, reference this page to ensure that you've installed everything properly.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlsrv.requirements.php

Comment: Yes I have correctly set the parameters of my servers.